# Aggregating data to 5 and 10 minutes

Tags: r, dataframe

My data contains 1-minute measurements that I would like to aggregate to 5 and 10 minutes. Of course, I could do this in excel but is there an easy way to do this in R?

**Sample data 1:**

```
    structure(list(Time = structure(c(0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 
360, 420, 480, 540, 600, 660, 720, 780, 840, 900, 960, 1020, 
1080, 1140, 1200, 1260, 1320, 1380, 1440, 1500, 1560, 1620, 1680, 
1740, 1800, 1860, 1920, 1980, 2040, 2100, 2160, 2220, 2280, 2340, 
2400, 2460, 2520, 2580, 2640, 2700, 2760, 2820, 2880, 2940, 3000, 
3060, 3120, 3180, 3240, 3300, 3360, 3420, 3480, 3540, 3600), class = c("hms", 
"difftime"), units = "secs"), Measurement = c(1.341667, 2.146667, 
2.683333, 2.683333, 2.683333, 2.415, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
2.951667, 1.61, 1.341667, 3.488333, 3.756667, 3.22, 2.951667, 
2.951667, 2.951667, 2.415, 2.415, 1.61, 1.341667, 2.683333, 2.683333, 
2.683333, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.146667, 1.341667, 
3.488333, 3.756667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 
2.951667, 1.341667, 1.341667, 2.683333, 2.683333, 2.415, 2.415, 
2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 2.415, 1.341667, 1.341667, 2.683333, 2.683333, 
2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 2.951667, 1.341667
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-61L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Time = structure(list(
    format = ""), class = c("collector_time", "collector")), 
    Measurement = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to aggregate data for every 5 minutes you can use `ceiling_date` from `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  group_by(Time = ceiling_date(as.POSIXct(Time), '5 minutes')) %>% 
  summarise(Measurement = mean(Measurement))
```

If you are ok converting your data to `xts` you could also do :

```
library(xts)

df$Time <- as.POSIXct(df$Time)
df_xts <- as.xts(df[, -1], order.by = df$Time)
period.apply(df_xts, endpoints(df_xts, on = "minutes", k = 5), mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zoo::rollapply` which allows the aggregation you'd like.

For example here `mean` (in this case you could also use directly `rollmean`):

```
library(zoo)

plot(data$Time,data$Measurement)
lines(data$Time,zoo::rollapply(data$Measurement,5,mean,fill=NA),col='red')
lines(data$Time,zoo::rollapply(data$Measurement,10,mean,fill=NA),col='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Also this works: `z <- read.zoo(data); plot(z, type = "p");
lines(rollmean(z, 5), col = "red");
lines(rollmean(z, 10), col = "blue")`